# How do the airlines allot the passengers seats to make sure the balance is maintained?

Tags: aircraft-design, airline-operations

How do the airlines allot the seats for the passengers?
Is there any procedure, like first front seats has to be filled next middle and at last the end seats?

Any algorithm works during the ticket booking to distribute the passengers according to their weight?

Comment: Weight is not a factor as the airlines have no idea how big their passengers are.

Comment: @GdD there are standard tables to estimate the weight of the passengers. See here: https://aviation.stackexchange.com/a/27943/1467

Comment: I'm aware of this @Federico, I'm saying that airlines do not have weight data on individual passengers.

Comment: @GdD no, they don't have the exact weight, but "weight is not a factor" is not correct, the weight given by those tables is very much a factor.

Comment: I think we are saying the same thing @Federico. Weight is very important, but individual weights of passengers is unknown so they use a value based on known factors.

Comment: During seat allocation (which they call "inventory management", airlines are more focused on group seating strategies (families, larger groups) and revenue (cabin partition) than mass balance (which may be tuned by cargo load distribution). [Reservation systems](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Airline_reservations_system) may include modules like "[seat inventory management](http://hdl.handle.net/1721.1/68123)" and "[load management](http://www.amadeus.com/web/binaries/blobs/618/788/amadeus_altea_departure_control_flight_management.pdf)"

Comment: Companies can use also some "[load and trim sheets](https://ahm.thy.com/Files/AHM560/Loadsheets/A340Binder1.pdf)". I also found this: https://www.skybrary.aero/index.php/Aircraft_Load_and_Trim

Answer (score 1):

It depends on the specific limitations of the aircraft and the flight booking load. If the flight is full, it not really an issue. Typically the check-in system will automatically distribute passengers throughout the cabin, starting from the front and moving backwards. Load planners may block rows during check-in if the flight is so empty the center of gravity will be exceeded, unless passengers sit in certain sections of the aircraft.