# Passengers Weight configuration

Tags: passenger

Well as usually when you fly in an airplane they Determine the luggage weight but how do they calculate the airplane weight "necessary so the plane doesn't get overweight" when they don't know the passengers weight and how do they deal with obesity (after my respect to all differences between people)

Comment: related, if not duplicate: https://aviation.stackexchange.com/q/27921/1467

Comment: It depends on the size of the plane. On a company-operated small bizjet, I've known situations where the pilot comes into the passenger cabin before takeoff and says  "OK, some of you need to change seats, I want to see the heavy guys sitting in the front seats and the light guys at the back".